# IntelliJ Idea: Red lines in dependency viewer

Tags: intellij-idea, diagram

I started experimenting with the different diagram views that intellij offers and stumbled upon the dependency view. In one of my projects I've encountered that besides the blue arrows indicating dependencies there are some dependencies that are shown using a red line. What is IntelliJ trying to tell me here. Does it hint at a possible or maybe definite issue?

[image: Intellij dependency view]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like dependencies with a red line are conflicting or unsatisfied dependencies.

There is any explanation here.
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/working-with-maven-dependencies.html

I was just looking at one of my projects and it looks like I have Guava conflict. I am bringing in version 15 but Guice is bringing in version 16.0.1. Need to fix that.
[image: Dependency graph conflict]

Comment: they all are blue, as well as test dependencies are green. Conflicting dependencies are marked red